# Angular-Ui-Router, nested named views - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to implement a very simple example using nested named views using ui-router, and I can't get it to work.  If anyone could look at this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/thardy/eD3MU/ - and tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

The basic idea is this:
- My index.html has a single ui-view
- The template that gets plugged into that has two, named ui-views
- I'm trying to setup the configuration to populate these two ui-views with templates and I can't get it to work

This is the core of the fiddle (angle brackets in template replaced with []):

```
        $stateProvider
            .state('test', {
                url: '/test',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                         template:  '[h1]Hello!!![/h1]' +
                                    '[div ui-view="view1"][/div]' +
                                    '[div ui-view="view2"][/div]'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('test.subs', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    'view1': {
                        template: "Im View1"
                    },
                    'view2': {
                        template: "Im View2"
                    }
                }
            });
```

I've tweaked it a alot for several hours now (trying absolute names, etc), and I'm about to go crazy.  It looks good according to the documentation (at least to me), but there aren't any simple examples, and I must be missing something obvious.

**Update**
By removing the url from test state and adding url: '' to the test.subs state, it works.  But adding any url to test state causes it to fail again.  In my real world scenario, none of these states are at the root, and having no url at all in the parent state causes things to not work well.  It's like that state isn't activated or something.  According to the docs, having url: '' in the sub should cause it to be activated along with it's parent state, but that's not what is happening.

**Update - Solution**
For any who would like to see it - http://jsfiddle.net/thardy/eD3MU/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

two issues in above code:

1. As kju suggested `abstract: true,`

   > An abstract state will never be directly activated, but can provide
   >   inherited properties to its common children states.
2. add `url: ""` in `test.sub` state

   > Using an empty url means that this child state will become active when
   >   its parent's url is navigated to.
3. Don't manual transition to "test"

See code below:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.state'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider',  
    function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('test', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                         template:  '<h1>Hello!!!</h1>' +
                                    '<div ui-view="view1"></div>' +
                                    '<div ui-view="view2"></div>'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('test.subs', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    'view1': {
                        template: "Im View1"
                    },
                    'view2': {
                        template: "Im View2"
                    }
                }
            });
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope,   $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
//        $state.transitionTo('test');
    }]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, with or without the abstract: true.  This is one of the many tweaks I tried earlier.  Play with the jsFiddle.  Hearty congratulations await anyone who can make it work :)

Comment: Ok, so if I don't add the abstract at all, remove the url from the test state and add it to the test.subs state, it "works".  Everything shows up, but I think there's still a problem.  In my real-world code, code that used to work in that controller is no longer working (I call endpoints, but nothing happens).  What I need is for both states to be active, or else to combine them into a single state somehow.  A simple way to see this is to have the test state be anything but "url: ''", and the child state be "url: ''".  It totally stops working again (sub views don't show up).

Comment: @TimHardy see my updated code. If you need both state to be activated, then you need to `transitionTo('test.subs')` or go to the url for `test.subs`

Comment: That was it!  Thank you so much.  It was the combination of the "abstract: true" on the base state with sub state having a url: ''. Base state can now have any url.  See my fiddle for the final result - http://jsfiddle.net/thardy/eD3MU/

Comment: @TimHardy Your fiddle solved my problem... which I was stumped at for a while. You should post your working fiddle in an update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add "abstract: true" to the "test" state. If you then transition to test.subs, you will see the subviews.

Comment: This didn't work.  This makes the "Hello!!!" disappear as well. You can try it in the jsFiddle.  In my case, the test state should and needs to be activated.

Comment: Also, perhaps I wasn't clear.  There is no "transitioning to the sub views".  I want the subs to show up on initial page load.  Perhaps this is where my problem lies.  When the user goes to "/", the root of the site, everything should be visible - "Hello!!!", as well as "Im View1" and "Im View2".